# Clarifying the PDE notation C^1([0,T], X).

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation, normed-spaces

In studying nonlinear hyperbolic PDE, I've come across the following spaces:

1. $C([0,T],H^s(\mathbb{R}^n))$.
2. $C^1([0,T], H^s(\mathbb{R}^n))$.
3. $L^p([0,T],H^s(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

I presume that $(1)$ consists of those maps $u:[0,T]\to H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that are continuous (in the metric) and that $(1)$ is a Banach space with norm 
\begin{align}||u||=\sup_{0\le t\le T}||u(t,x)||_{H^s_x(\mathbb{R}^n)}\end{align}

Now, (3) seems like no stretch of the imagination either; it's the collection of Borel measurable functions from $[0,T]$ to $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that satisfy \begin{align}
||u||=\left(\int_{0}^{T}||u(t,x)||_{H^s_x(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{p}\ dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty
\end{align} Alternatively, one may rigorously define the notion of integrating a Banach space valued function as, for example, Evans does. What has me stuck is $(2)$. I'm new to this field, and haven't encountered this notation (I'm reading Sogge's notes). Does this mean that the difference quotients \begin{align}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||u(t_0+h,x)-u(t,x)||_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}}{h}
\end{align}exists for every $t_0\in [0,T]$?. Perhaps this means that the spatial weak derivatives lie in $C([0,T],H^(\mathbb{R}^n))$, or that the weak time derivatives do? Could you help me parse this? Also, what would the norm be for whichever the correct answer be? Lastly, in the interest of teaching me to fish; could you direct me to a source that rigorously defines (2)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces and $U\subset X$ open. A function $u\colon U\to Y$ is said to be differentiable at $a\in U$ if there exists a linear operator $Du_a\colon X\to Y$ (the differential of $u$ at $a$) such that
$$
u(a+h)=u(a)+Du_a(h)+o(h).
$$
If $u$ is continuous, then $Du_a$ is also continuous. If $u$ is continuous and differentiable at very point of $U$, this defines a map $Du\colon U\to\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$, the space of linear continuous operators from $X$ to $Y$. If this map is continuous, $u$ is said to be $C^1$.

In your case $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is an interval and $Y=H^s$. The differential is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $Y$. It can be written as $Du_a(t)=t\,u'_a$ where $u'_a=Du_a(1)$. Then the definition of differentiability is
$$
u(a+h)=u(a)+h\,u'_a+o(h).
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{u(a+h)-u(h)}{h}=u'_a.
$$
If the map $a\in U\mapsto u'_a\in Y$ is continuous, $u$ is $C^1$.