# Energy Estimate for Nonlinear Wave Equation in $H^s$ Space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

In Theorem 2.1 of Prof. Lawrie notes (which can be found [here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ealawrie/Topic%20Proposal%20long%20copy.pdf)), he provided without proof the following result:

> Let $(f,g)\in H^s\times H^{s-1}$ and $h\in L^1([0,T], H^{s-1})$. Then the linear wave equation
> $$\begin{cases}
> \Box u = h \\
> u(0,x) = f(x)\\
> \partial_tu(0,x) = g(x)
> \end{cases}$$
> has a unique solution $u\in C([0,T],H^s)\cap C^1([0,T],H^{s-1})$ which satisfies, for each $0\le t\le T$, the following energy estimates:
> $$
> \|u(t,\cdot)\|_{H^s} + \|\partial_t u(t,\cdot)\|_{H^{s-1}} \le C(1+t)\left(\|f\|_{H^s} + \|g\|_{H^{s-1}} + \int_0^t\|h(\tau,\cdot)\|_{H^{s-1}} d\tau\right)
> $$

To this theorem, I have three questions:

1. I am not too worried about the uniqueness but I have no idea how to proof the inequality. In particular, how should I bound $\|u(t,\cdot)\|_{H^s}$? I've tried the energy method with $E(t):=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u(t,x)|^2\,dx$ but I didn't have much success with this. How do I make the $(1+t)$ appear when bounding this term?
2. When bounding $\|\partial_t u(t,\cdot)\|_{H^{s-1}}$, I used integration by parts and simply discarded the boundary term; am I allowed to do that? The working for that portion looks like this
   \begin{align}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\partial u)\cdot(\partial_t\partial u)dx
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left[(\partial_t u)(\partial_t^2 u) + \sum_{i=1}^n (\partial_i u)(\partial_i \partial_t u)\right]dx \\
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left[(\partial_t u)(\partial_t^2 u) - \sum_{i=1}^n (\partial_i^2 u)(\partial_t u)\right]dx 
   \end{align}
3. What is going on with all the spaces here? What is $h\in L^1([0,T], H^{s-1})$? Isn't the function $h$ suppose to be $\mathbb{R}^{1+n}\to\mathbb{R}$? Then how can it be a map of $[0,T]\to H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R^n})$? And what does $u\in C([0,T],H^s)\cap C^1([0,T],H^{s-1})$ mean? How do you even intersect these two spaces? I'm really perplexed by this so please help shed some light here. (I know [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690731/clarifying-the-pde-notation-c10-t-x?noredirect=1&lq=1), to some extent, discuss this but whatever is going on there makes no sense to me as well)

Any help would be appreciated; thanks in advance.

Comment: I took a look at the note. Prof. Lawrie did prove Theorem 2.1 in his note.  It may help.

Comment: Yea, I saw it after making this post. If my understanding is correct, he used Fourier transform which resulted in $u$ being a distribution. But shouldn't $u$ be a function since $u\in C(...)\cap C^1(...)$. I was wondering if this proof can be done without invoking distribution (I don't mind a non-optimum $C$ if necessary).

Comment: Also, if possible, do you have any idea what's going on with all the spaces (as per point 3 of my question)? Prof Lawrie did not give the definition of his notation. I presume it's a common knowledge so he omitted it but I'm new to this field so it'll be good for me to see the definition at least once.

Comment: I answered point 3 of your question below. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the wave equations. I will answer point 1 and 2 if I have any ideas.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I'll try to figure out the other two points on my own.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of the third question, although the function $h=h(t,x)$ is from $ [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. One can fix a $t\in [0,T]$ to regard $h(t,\cdot)$ as a function of $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Varying $t\in [0,T]$, we get a map from $[0,T]$ to $H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So basically we can regard the function $h$ as a map:$[0,T]\to H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

In this way, one can define the space $L^1([0,T];H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ by
$$
 \| h \|_{L^1([0,T];H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))}:= \int^T_0 \| h(t,\cdot) \|_{H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\,dt <\infty.
$$

For the second part, similarly, $u \in C([0,T],H^s)$ means that we regard $u$ as a map $t\to u(t,\cdot)$ and this map is continuous and lies in the space $C([0,T],H^s)$ with
$$
 \| u \|_{C([0,T];H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n))}:= \max_{0\leq t \leq T} \| u(t,\cdot) \|_{H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)} <\infty.
$$
To define the space $C^1([0,T],H^{s-1})$, it requires the map $t\to u(t,\cdot)$ is continuously differentiable. The norm of $C^1([0,T],H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is therefore given by
$$
 \| u\|_{C^1([0,T],H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))}:= \| u \|_{C([0,T],H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))}+\| u'\|_{C([0,T],H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))},
$$
where $u'$ denotes the Fréchet derivative of the map $t \to u(t,\cdot)$. Of course, $u\in  C([0,T],H^s)\cap C^1([0,T],H^{s-1})$ means $u\in C([0,T],H^s)$ and $u\in C^1([0,T],H^{s-1})$.

Comment: I saw that you self-deleted your answer to a poor-quality question. Thank you for helping to maintain site quality!